# Check contents of $_COOKIE for a string

Tags: php

When I run `var_dump($_COOKIE)` I get the following output:

```
array(9) {
    ["wordpress_test_cookie"] => string(15)
    "WP Cookie check" 
    ["wp-postpass_299da1fd9cb967a93782c5397fa3a35e"] => string(34)
    "$P$BXtsZ0i1qom3bqiFk4b9GeG8l9dFVG." 
}
```

I want to check the contents of `$_COOKIE` for the existence of `wp-postpass_` elements.

I tried:
`if(strpos($_COOKIE,'wp-postpass_') === 0) {` but this didn't work.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: First of all `strpos` method expects parameter one to be string not an array `$_COOKIE` is an array

Comment: you gotta loop through whole all cookies and search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(isset($_COOKIE)){
    foreach($_COOKIE as $key=>$val){
        if(strpos($key,'wp-postpass_') === false) {
        //not found
        }else{
        //found
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wouldnt it be nice to do stuff when found?

Comment: Fantastic :-) Just added an else to cover 'Found' : )

Comment: Will green tick answer shortly. Many thanks for your time, Bhaskar - it is greatly appreciated. Have a wonderful day.

Comment: I am glad my answer helped you. :)

Answer (score 1):

strpos does not work on array. you should scan all array elements and look for the string.

Comment: That was a silly mistake, wasn't it? :-) Will investigate `in_array` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<?php
    function searchCookie( $name )
    {
        foreach( $_COOKIE as $key => $value ){
            if( inString( $key, $name ){
                    return $value;
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    function inString( $str, $search )
    {
        return str_replace( $search , '' , $str ) != $str;
    }

    $cookie = searchCookie( 'wp-postpass' );

    if( $cookie == null ){
        echo 'Cookie not found :(';
    }
    else{
        echo $cookie;
    }
```